# Which folder to add custom helper functions to in Yii

Tags: yii2

I am trying to create a helper function in Yii 2. To which folder is the PHP file to be added to create a custom helper function in Yii 2 and how do I use it in controllers?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can put it in the components folder. Afterwards use the namespace to access it. For example

```
use app\components\Helper;
```

and in your code

```
Helper::something();
```

Make the helper functions static functions.

Comment: There was no folder called components in basic template. So I just created a folder called helpers in app and followed your way and it worked.

Comment: you got the idea yes, just make it to suit how you want it to work.

Comment: @MihaiP. Good answer, why should the methods be static though. I'm just going to write some of my own and not sure why you say this?

Comment: @Jonnny they do not have to be. They can be however you want/need.

Comment: @MihaiP What is the pros and cons to them being static in this case?

Comment: @Jonnny Try to use static methods for very, very simple things.

Answer (score 12):

To create some static helpers do the following (these instructions are for the 'Advanced Yii2 Template'.
Create a folder under `common` called `components`. Inside there create a class called something like: `MyHelpers` (filename `MyHelpers.php`).

```
<?php
namespace common\components;
// namespace app\components; // For Yii2 Basic (app folder won't actually exist)
class MyHelpers
{
    public static function hello($name) {
        return "Hello $name";
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include it in your controller etc that you would like to use it in.
    `use common\components\MyHelpers;`
    `// use app\components\MyHelpers; // For Yii2 Basic (app folder won't actually exist)`

And to use it:
    `MyHelpers::hello("John");`

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

*CREATE an Helpers.php in (is a function without class, for that reason is a helper):

```
/components
```

p.e. I use a function to debug:

```php
<?php
namespace app\components\Helpers;
// +-----------------------------------------------
// | @author          : Carlos Gomez
// | @created_at      : 18/03/2022
// | @updated_by      : 
// | @Version (branch): FEAT-001-2022
// +-----------------------------------------------
// Add ___ function.
// +---------------------------


/**
 * ___
 *
 * @param  mixed $xVariable
 * @param  mixed $bBreakPoint
 * @param  mixed $bDumpMode
 * @param  mixed $type
 * @param  mixed $line
 * @return void
 */
function ___($xVariable, $bBreakPoint = true, $bDumpMode = false, $type = '000', $line = 0) {
    echo "<pre>";
        if (!$bDumpMode) {
            print_r($xVariable);
        }
        else {
            var_dump($xVariable);
        }
    echo '</pre>';

    if ($bBreakPoint) {
        exit($line);
    }
}
```

2.- *ADD the autoload in composer.json with the path of the helpers php file.

```json
...

"autoload":{
        "files": [
            "components/Helpers.php"
        ]
    }
...
```

3. *RUN in terminal (In your current project folder):

```
composer dump-autoload
```

4. *IMPLEMENT the function using "use" in the file that you need:

```php
use function app\components\Helpers\___; //-> After namespace obviously

...

___( $variableToDebug ); //-> In any part of your code when you need to use the function.
I hope this can be useful to anybody.
```

Answer (score -1):

For example, `models->helpers->SomeHelper.php`
In your controller this helper will access like `\models\helpers\SomeHelper.php`